# Validar un JSON e imprimirlo formateado

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Supongamos que copio en un textarea una cadena por ejemplo:

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";
```

Por lo que con `JSON.parse(str)` parseo el string en formato JSON, pero me gustaría mostrar el resultado en un textarea o algo parecido y formateado-

Además, si modifica algo de ahí y está mal, que de un error. Algo parecido a esta web: https://jsonformatter.org/

Mi controller:

```
$scope.toParseJson= function (str) {
   $scope.jsonValue = str;
}

$scope.validateJson= function (str) {
   $scope.errors= JSON.parse(str);
}
```

Mi html

```
<textarea ng-change="toParseJson(str)" ng-model="str"></textarea><br>
{{errors}}<br>
<textarea ng-change="validateJson(str)" ng-model="jsonValue "></textarea>
```

1- ¿Cómo consigo que en el segundo textarea me aparezca ordeando con sus tabulaciones y diferenciando?

2- ¿Hay otra manera elegante de mostrar los errores?

Comment: No es complicado, pero has probado a hacer algo? Aqui la gente esta para echar un cable, no hacerte las cosas. Cuelga parte de tu código, muestra tus errores... Echale un ojo a [ask]

Comment: Edito mi pregunta, con código, un saludo

Comment: *con JSON.parse(str) parseo el string a json* **No**, el string es el JSON, `JSON.parse()` crea un objeto Javascript. `Javascript Object != Javascript Object Notation`, tengamos claros los conceptos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Validar un JSON**

El método [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) lanza un [SyntaxError](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/SyntaxError) si la sintaxis es inválida:

```js
let textoJSON = '{ "hello": "world" <<<ERROR>>> "places": ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Australia"] }',
    objeto;

try {
    objeto = JSON.parse(textoJSON);
    console.log('Sintaxis Correcta');
}
catch (error) {
    if(error instanceof SyntaxError) {
        let mensaje = error.message;
        console.log('ERROR EN LA SINTAXIS:', mensaje);
    } else {
        throw error; // si es otro error, que lo siga lanzando
    }
}
```

---

**Imprimir un JSON formateado**

El método [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) convierte un objeto a JSON, y acepta un tercer parámetro con la cantidad de espacios para usar en cada tabulación. Imprimí el resultado en un contenedor que respete los espacios en blanco (ej: un `<pre>` o un `<textarea>`).

```js
let textoJSON = '{ "hello": "world", "places": ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Australia"] }',
    objeto;
    
//Teniendo un objeto...
objeto = JSON.parse(textoJSON);

//Lo convertimos a JSON formateado con 2 espacios
let textoFormateado = JSON.stringify(objeto, undefined, 2);

//Imprimimos
document.write('<pre>' + textoFormateado + '</pre>');
```

Comment: gracias Mariano, tuve que hacer unos pequeños cambios para hacer lo que realmente necesitaba pero con tu gran ejemplo me fue fácil